# ¿Por qué se generan múltiples instancias de mi grupo de aplicaciones?

Tags: asp.net, webservice, iis, windows-server-2012

Tengo publicado un web services en Windows Server 2012 R2, este servicio recibe al rededor 3000 request al día.

Funcionamiento general del servicio:

- El servicio inicia "vacío", cuando recibe la primera solicitud se ejecuta un proceso que carga una serie de catálogos en memoria(la carga en memoria es requerimiento no me permiten modificar este proceso).
- La información recibida se valida contra los catálogos para determinar si los datos son correctos o no.
- Cuando se recibe una 2da solicitud y el servicio continua configurándose retorna una excepción diciendo que el servicio se esta configurando que lo intente más tarde.
- Cuando se recibe otra solicitud y el servicio ya esta configurado, ya no carga los catálogos, pues ya los tiene en la memoria. Estos catálogos se actualizan cada 24hr.
- El servicio tiene su propio grupo de aplicaciones donde se configuro un reciclado cada 25hrs en una especifica.

Mi problema es:
- Al observar el administrador de tareas veo que mi grupo de aplicaciones tiene 2 instancias y las dos cargan los catálogos pero solo veo actividad de procesamiento en 1.

- Como puedo configurar para que solo sea una instancia evitando esa doble carga y consumo innecesario de memoria?
- Alguna sugerencia de configuración para IIS?
- Alguna propiedad de IIS en la que tenga que tener cuidado por consumo de memoria y que me este afectando el servicio?
- Algún punto que tenga considerar?

Cualquier comentario y/o sugerencia sera bien recibido.
Saludos y gracias.

Comment: ¿De qué manera ves el grupo de aplicaciones en el administrador de tareas? El grupo de aplicaciones o `Application Pool` corre bajo el servicio del IIS, el cual también puedes encontrar bajo el proceso `w3wp.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

Continué investigando y haciendo algunas pruebas junto con un amigo y el parecer encontramos en *IIS* la propiedad que soluciono el problema.

Trabajando con *Windows Server 2012 y IIS* si nos costo un poco encontrar y entender la definición de esa propiedad.

Comparto nuestra solución:
A nuestro grupo de aplicaciones sobre el que trabaja nuestro servicio modificamos la propiedad:
**Configuración Avanzada > Modelo de proceso > Máximo de procesos de trabajo**
El valor por default es **0** pero nosotros lo modificamos a **1**.

Este cambio soluciono el problema sobre nuestro servicio y también lo aplicamos sobre los grupos de aplicaciones que atienden a algunas paginas que tenemos.